# Why does Internet Gatway have to be added to Route Tables to receive internet traffic?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Route tables describe the destination of packets from within a VPC so why does a route table have to include an internet gateway when the internet gatway is the source of the packet and the destination is the public or elastic IPs within the VPC?

Answer (score 1):

Because almost every useful internet connection is bidirectional.  TCP/IP connections require several packets back and forth before a connection is established and even if, abstractly, all of the data is going one way, there's a flow of acknowledgement packets returning to the sender.

This isn't the case with UDP/IP, but I don't know exactly what traffic you're trying to send back end forth.

One thing you could try is to install tcpdump (or similar) on the instance, and see if it receives the packets.  (It is possible to do this without the AWS IGW, however, it will require a second VPC, VPC peering, and a bit of clever network configuration.)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a subnet,It will be automatically associate it with the main route table for the VPC. By default, the main route table doesn't contain a route to an Internet gateway.So we have to add the route.

Use case:

Assume You have multiple subnets in your VPC and you want to restrict only few subnets should interact with internet, You can restrict by adding the Routes(Destination as 0.0.0.0/0 or single IP/URL and target as your IGW)in Route table. After doing this,which are the subnets are associated with this route table will connect internet via IGW and others will be routed based on Main route table.

Ref :https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html